# How to fix errors given by indexer?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have setup a azure search indexer based on the documents in blob storage. when the indexer runs, it throws some errors. what should I do to avoid these errors?

I checked documentation, I don't see any suggestions for these errors. These are the errors reported

Skill #3: An error occurred when attempting to obtain language from portions of input text
Skill #2: An error occurred when attempting to obtain key phrases from portions of input text

Answer (score 0):

A skill can produce errors and warnings.
Errors are considered critical (something should at least be investigated), while Warnings are more informational (It is possible nothing is wrong, but we consider that information worthy of the customer's knowledge/investigation).

How do you investigate the error?
Usually I like to look at the inputs into the skill to understand what may wrong (maybe the type of text provided is not real human text?). It can be helpful to generate the enriched field that contains the whole tree of information so you can see what the inputs look like. See tip#4 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-troubleshooting .

Let's say you have fixed any errors you consider worthy and want to ignore the rest... what do you do?
You can tell the indexer to ignore errors, and proceed doing its job by setting the maxFailedItems and maxFailedItemsPerBatch to -1. (See Tip #3 on the troubleshooting page)

> {
>     "// rest of your indexer definition
>      "parameters":
>      {
>         "maxFailedItems":-1,
>         "maxFailedItemsPerBatch":-1
>      }
>   }

If you think you have identified a bug with one of the skills and it is producing an error when it should not, please send bug reports to azuresearch_contact@microsoft.com

Thanks!
-Luis Cabrera (Microsoft)